# How to install Sails js via npm through a firewall

Tags: git, github, https, npm, sails.js

I've installed Sails on my home computer fine, however I'm trying to install it on my working machine and I can't get it installed because at work I'm behind a firewall, so I can't use git clone  and have to use git clone https://.

The problem is that Sail's npm packages makes a lot of request to git repositories through the former command (git clone git://) and the installation fails.

Any ideas how can I get npm to request https rather than git?